# WCF service with both HTTPS and HTTP endpoint

Tags: wcf, ssl, iis-7, endpoints

I have successfully configured a WCF service that uses mutual certificate authentication with a WCF client over SSL.

For the mutual authentication over HTTPS the client and server both have certificates, and have exchanged their public keys out of band, so WCF is explicitly checking the client or server respectively to make sure the right certificate is used.

**Problem:**

I now need to expose an HTTP endpoint for a PHP client where the message will be encrypted manually at the client and decrypted manually at the WCF service.

Initially I had the 'Require SSL' setting set to 'Require' in IIS 7, but now I tried to change that to 'Accept' so that IIS would accept the non-https traffic and configured another wsHttpBinding endpoint with no security on the service. Both endpoints have relative addresses.

I am getting the following error:
**The SSL settings for the service 'SslRequireCert' does not match those of the IIS 'SslNegotiateCert'.**

Is what I am attempting to do possible with WCF and IIS? I thought it would be relatively simple to set up an additional endpoint with a different binding.

Comment: totally possible, I wrestled with this for a bit till i found the answer too.  What version of WCF are you using though?  WCF 4 REST?  That is the version that i found the solution for me.  If so i'll send you what i have.  it's a web.config change (you should probably include your relavant web.config section anyways)